# How can I use interactive rebase to merge last 2 pull requests?

Tags: git, rebase, pull-request

I made a pull request yesterday, call it PR1.

I had to make a change afterward, and forgot to `git commit --amend` and instead just did a commit and made another pull request (call it PR2).

How can I merge PR2 into PR1? I believe there is a way to do it with interactive rebasing, but I am not sure how it works.

Comment: `git checkout <branch-for-PR1>; git merge <branch-for-PR2>`? The `git rebase` command doesn't do merges (although in this particular case the outcome might be the same).

Comment: @mkrieger1 I made the pull request from the same branch, so I'm confused how those commands you listed would work (I'm not too well versed with git)? The maintainer of the code base suggested to use interactive rebase, but I'm not sure how that would work in this case either

Comment: If you only have one branch, you don't have to do anything. Just use PR2 and ignore PR1. However, it's a bit unclear to me what your exact situation is and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry for the confusion. Maybe I'm not explaining the situation correctly. I'm working on Pytorch for context. I think my last comment may have been mistaken as I confused *remote* and *local* branches. Each time I make a pull request, it seems to make a new remote branch (I was working on the same local branch when making the pull requests), so I think your comment makes more sense to me now. What I ended up doing was closing PR2, undoing the commit locally, amending and then updating PR1.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The maintainer suggested "also you can use interactive rebase to merge this PR to the previous one: `git rebase -i origin/master`" but I don't know how that merges PR2 to PR1.